# Why use the" have+p.p "in this sentence?

Tags: tense

> Once you've obtained your precious ticket, you can relax in the cafe with a snack and an ice cold drink as huskies roam around on the hunt for some snacks.

1. Why use “you've obtained” in the sentence, isn't use the present tenses ?
2. What is the “as” meaning in the sentence?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

*Once you obtain your ticket* is also possible here. There is no difference in the events referred to, just in how the writer is choosing to structure them in time.

If they said

> Once you obtain your ticket, you can relax in the cafe ...

the viewpoint would be moving forward through the narrative: first you get your ticket, then you relax in the cafe.

But with

> Once you have obtained your ticket, you can relax in the cafe ...

the viewpoint is fixed at the time you are in the cafe, and looking backward to the time when you got the ticket.

*As* here means the same as *while*.

Answer (score 0):

You have obtained tickets.
Meaning  action is in complete state.
So we are using the perfect tense here.
Moreover the action is completed in near future so it is present perfect tense

Comment: You apparently need to get the ticket _before_ you can eat in the café. The huskies are roaming round while patrons are sitting in the café.